# Find Column Header By Name And Move All Data Below Column Header (Excel-VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post...

I’m attempting to create macro to do the following:

1. Search a spreadsheet column header by name.
2. Select all data from the selected column, including column header.
3. Move selected column to the first column.

I have around 100 columns in the spreadsheet and those columns are likely generated in different order every period.

I would like to search and move 10 specific columns next to each other in the front for easy reference to work with. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Position As Range
    Dim strHeader As String

    strHeader = "Marios"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<- Find the last column of row 1

        Set Position = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastColumn)).Find(strHeader) '<- Search from column 1 to last column of row 1 for the header

        If Position Is Nothing Then '<- If header does not excist throw a message box
            MsgBox "Header was not found."
        Else '<- If header does excist
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Position.Column).End(xlUp).Row '<- Find the last row of the column that header found

            .Range(.Cells(1, Position.Column), .Cells(LastRow, Position.Column)).Cut '<- Cut the column that found from row  to last row
            .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight '<- Move ate column A

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Apology for the delay response. By far this one works perfectly for the purpose. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one (not tested):

```
Dim wb as Workbook, ws as Worksheet
Dim column_header as String 'Name of the header to be found

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 'Set corresponding sheet
column_header = "test_header"

Dim column_range as Range 'Cell of the header of interest
Set column_range = ws.Rows(1).Find(column_header, LookIn:=xlValues)

Columns(column_range.Column).Cut 'Cut column with the right header
Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to solve problems like yours in Excel. This is probably not the best one but it should work:

**For 1:**

If your table has around 100 columns and assuming it begins in cell A1 you can use

```
intColNr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeaderToSearch,Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("A1:DZ1"),0)
```

to get the column you search for (A:DZ are 130 columns => should cover your needs).

**For 2/3:**

Assuming your table has not more than 100.000 rows:
First insert a new column in column A:

```
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Then copy/paste the column you found in step 1:

```
Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range(Worksheets("MyWorksheet").cells(1,intColNr),Worksheets("MyWorksheet").cells(100000,intColNr)).copy

Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("A1").pastespecial xlPasteAll
```

If you don't want the columns to be duplicated you should delete the column you found in step 1 (since we inserted a new column in front its column number increases by 1):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range(Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(1,intColNr  + 1),Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(1,intColNr + 1)).entirecolumn.delete
```

Put all of the aboove inside a Sub, e.g. subMoveColumn(varHeader as Variant) and put the headers you want to search for inside a range, e.g. Worksheets("Someworksheet").Range("A1:A10") and loop through that range:

```
Set rngHeaders = Worksheets("Someworksheet").Range("A1:A10")
For varHeader in rngHeaders 
   subMoveColumn(varHeader)
Next
```

This is not a ready to use solution but I hope it helps.